# GLSL fragmentshader like css clippath

Tags: three.js, glsl, fragment-shader

Is there a way to "crop" of a certain part of an image with a fragmentshader like with a css clippath? I am trying to do this on a three js texture and I have gotten this from prisoner849:
https://jsfiddle.net/cn8gv3sL/
It uses the `baseLayerSize` to get the size of the rectangle, and then to figure out to remove it or not. I would like this to work with a polygon of any type instead of a rectangle only.

```c
vec2 d = abs(vPos.xy - baseLayerPosition.xy) - baseLayerSize * 0.5;
float f = length(max(d,0.0)) + min(max(d.x,d.y),0.0);
if (f >= 0.) discard;
```

Is there an easy way to give the fragmentshader a polygon and it can determine if it's inside or outside and then draw it based on that?

I basically would like the code from the jsfiddle to work with any type of polygon.

Comment: *"Is there an easy way to give the fragment shader a polygon and it can determine if it's inside or outside ..."* No, unfortunately not. You need to implement all of the math required to see if there is a point inside a polygon in the fragment shader. How would you like to represent the polygon?

Comment: I'm guessing that the easiest way to do this sort of thing would be to pass in a texture with the shape that you're wanting and use that as a map for the clipping.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses! I understand that this is not really something you can do. I had two ideas for passing the polygon, either the coordinates of the corners or a css clip-path style.